# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python, pytorch

У меня есть файл, содержащий модель обученной нейронной сети и пример кода, который должен эту модель сохранять/загружать.

```
PATH ="/content/drive/MyDrive/nn_x1x2.pytorch_model_file"

if False:
    print( f'Сохранение в файл "{PATH}" ')
    torch.save(nn_x1x2, PATH)
else:
    print( f'Загрузка из файла "{PATH}" ')
    nn_x1x2 = torch.load(PATH)
    nn_x1x2.eval()
```

Но при попытке запустить его, я получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Я пока только начал изучать анализ данных на python. Подскажите пожалуйста,  что здесь не так? И как это можно исправить?

Comment: Я бы проверил для начала что у вас в `nn_x1x2` перед `save` находится.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.load()` скорее всего возвращает `np.array`.

Чтобы подгрузить модель в pytorch используйте [это  руководство](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)

```py
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).